# How to check if data is still in memory

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory, virtual-memory

Say I allocate some memory of whatever size

```
void* p = malloc(WHATEVER_SIZE);
```

Later on I want to check (perhaps using a system call) which bytes of that data is in physical memory and how many page swaps need to happen in order to retrieve the ones that are not. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Linux or a similar system, try the [`mincore`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mincore.2.html) syscall. It gives you a bit vector representing, for a range of pages, which ones are physically resident at the time of the call. Of course this information could be outdated by the time you use it; it's inherently subject to a [TOCTOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) race unless the pages are locked.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up the [Time of check to time of use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) issue.